# How to display special chars in html

Tags: php, html, encoding, character-encoding

I have a web page and suddenly it is displaying spcecial characters as asian characters like ñ is display as 帽 this is the head of my template

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Administrador</title>
<!-- no index -->
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem might be the encoding of the file.
Open it in notepad++ and change the to UTF-8 (without bom).